# Angle Normalization C#

Tags: c#, math, angle, pi

I have an Angle class that has this constructor

```
public  Angle(int deg, //  Degrees, minutes, seconds
                  int min, //    (Signs should agree
                  int sec) //       for conventional notation.)
{
   /* //Bug degree normalization 
    while (deg <= -180) deg += 360;
    while (deg > Math.PI) deg -= 360;
    //correction end */

    double seconds = sec + 60 * (min + 60 * deg);
    value = seconds * Math.PI / 648000.0;
    normalize(); 
}
```

and I have these values for testing that constructor

```
  int[] degrees = { 0, 180, -180, Int32.MinValue / 60, 120+180*200000};
        int[] minutes = { 0, 0, 0, 0,56};
        int[] seconds = { 0, 0, 0, 0,10};
        Console.WriteLine("Testing constructor Angle(int deg, int min)");
        for (int i = 0; i < degrees.Length; i++)
        {

            p = new Angle(degrees[i], minutes[i], seconds[i]);
            Console.WriteLine("p = " + p);
        }
        /*Testing constructor Angle(int deg, int min)
        p = 0°0'0"
        p = 180°0'0"
        p = 180°0'0"
        p = 0°8'0" incorrect output 
        p = -73°11'50"  incorrect output expected  120 56 10 
         */
```

I do not understand why there is a bug here ?  and why did they use divide Int32.MinValue by 60 and 120+180*200000 as this format ?

the comments in the constructor is a correction for the code

**UPDATE**: Added the code of `normalize()`

```
//  For compatibility with the math libraries and other software
//  range is (-pi,pi] not [0,2pi), enforced by the following function:  

void normalize()
{
    double twoPi = Math.PI + Math.PI;          
    while (value <= -Math.PI) value += twoPi;
    while (value >   Math.PI) value -= twoPi;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?  Are you asking how to ensure an angle is between 0 and 2pi or are you asking how your output was reached?  If it's the latter, you will need to show your normalize() function.  One common problem with this type of challenge is you only account for the first two rotations and nothing more than that.  You need to make sure your normalize() function takes into account angles greater than 4pi.

Comment: while (deg > Math.PI) deg -= 360; this line makes no sense... You surely mean deg > 180

Comment: Using a `while` loop to wrap values is a _bad_ idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this piece of code:

```
double seconds = sec + 60 * (min + 60 * deg);
```

Although you are storing `seconds` as a `double`, the conversion from `int` to `double` is taking place *after* `sec + 60 * (min + 60 * deg)` is computed **as an `int`**.

The compiler will not choose `double` arithmetics for you based on the type you decide to store the result in. The compiler will choose the best operator overload based on the *types of the operands* which in this case are all `int` and look for a valid implicit conversion (in this case `int` to `double`) *afterwards*; therefore it is choosing `int` arithmetics and the operation will overflow in the last two test cases:

`Int32.MinValue / 60 * 60 * 60` = `Int32.MinValue * 60` < `Int32.MinValue` which will overflow.

`120 + 180 * 200000 * 60 * 60` > `Int32.MaxValue` which will also overflow.

Your expected results for these two cases are probably not considering this behavior.

In order to solve this issue, change your code to:

```
double seconds = sec + 60 * (min + 60f * deg);
```

Explicitly setting `60` to a `double` typed literal constant (`60f`) will force the compiler to resolve all operations to `double` arithmetics.

Also, it is worth pointing out that your constructor logic has some other issues:

1. You should be validating the input data; should it be valid to specify negative minutes or seconds? IMO that doesn't seem reasonable. Only `deg` should be allowed to have a negative value. You should check for this condition and act accordingly: throw an exception (preferable) or normalize sign of `min` and `sec` based on the sign of `deg` (ugly and potentially confusing).
2. Your `seconds` calculation doesn't seem to be correct for negative angles (again, this is tied to the previous issue and whatever sign convention you have decided to implement). Unless the convention is that negative angles must have negative `deg`, `min` and `sec`, the way you are computing `seconds` is wrong because you are always adding the minutes and seconds terms no matter the sign of `deg`.

**UPDATE** There is one more issue in your code that I missed until I had the chance to test it. Some of your test cases are failing because `double` doesn't have enough resolution. I think your code needs some major refactoring; `normalize()` should be called first. This way you will always be managing tightly bounded values that can not cause overflows or precision loss.

This is the way I would do it:

```
 public Angle(int deg, int min, int sec)
 {
     //Omitting input values check.

     double seconds = sec + 60 * (min + 60 * normalize(deg));
     value = seconds * Math.PI / 648000f;
 }

 private int normalize(int deg)
 {
     int normalizedDeg = deg % 360;

     if (normalizedDeg <= -180)
         normalizedDeg += 360;
     else if (normalizedDeg > 180)
         normalizedDeg -= 360;

     return normalizedDeg;
 }
```

Comment: when I tried to change to  double seconds = sec + 60 * (min + 60f * deg).. it gives me the final result for Int32.MinValue / 60 as  167°59'0".. why does it change the min to 59. I think the correct output should be 166 0 0 ..right ? but it gives me the expected output for the last value which is 120°56'10"..

Comment: Your method is incorrent, it only normalizes values between -360 and 360. Everything beyond won't be normalized.

Answer (score 0):

```
    //  For compatibility with the math libraries and other software
//  range is (-pi,pi] not [0,2pi), enforced by the following function:  

void normalize()
{double twoPi = Math.PI + Math.PI;          
    while (value <= -Math.PI) value += twoPi;
    while (value >   Math.PI) value -= twoPi;
}
```

This is the normalize function that I have

Comment: Do not answer your own question to provide more info. Edit your question adding the new information and point it out with an **UPDATE** notice describing the new information and how its is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

`while` loops is generally a bad idea. If you deal with small values it's okay, but imagine you have some angle like 1e+25, that'd be 1.59e+24 iterations or about 100 million years to compute if you have a decent CPU.
How it should be done instead:

```
static double NormalizeDegree360(double value)
{
    var result = value % 360.0;
    return result > 0 ? result : result + 360;
}
static double NormalizeDegree180(double value)
{
    return (((value + 180) % 360) + 360) % 360 - 180;
}
static double TwoPI = 2*System.Math.PI;
static double NormalizeRadians2Pi(double value)
{
    var result = value % TwoPI;
    return result > 0 ? result : result + TwoPI;
}
static double NormalizeRadiansPi(double value)
{
    return (((value + System.Math.PI) % TwoPI) + TwoPI) % TwoPI - System.Math.PI;
}
```

Comment: Not completely sure, but I think ternary operator with comparison should be faster than second modulus operator (which basically should have same speed as division (somewhere between 10-50 ops), while comparison is basically subtraction (2 ops) and ternary operator is one conditional jump, which usually is 1 or 2 ops).

Answer (score -1):

They're using the very large negative and positive numbers to make sure that the normalization caps angles to the range [-180, 180] degrees properly.